# Could someone review this MySQL left join statement? It's not returning all the data I want

Tags: php, mysql

Im creating a project site that is a basic classifieds for video games. Currently I have 2 tables, categories and classifieds.

---

**Rows in "classifieds" table:**

id (PK)

title

content

contact

date

categories_id (FK)

**Rows in "categories" table:**

id (PK)

name

---

I want it to return each category (currently there are 3 - xbox, playstation, wii) with the number of ads in each category (1 in each currently)

The problem I'm having is its returning only one category (the first one - xbox) and saying "3 ads" (the total amount of ads in all categories)

I'm sure the solution is simple, I just need another set of eyes to look at it. Thanks in advance! The PHP function I'm using is posted below:

```
function list_count()
{
   $q="SELECT COUNT(tA.id) as classifieds, tC.name as name, tC.id as id
   FROM categories as tC LEFT JOIN classifieds as tA ON tA.categories_id=tC.id
   ORDER BY tC.name";
   $result=mysql_query($q);
   $cats=array();

   while($cat=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {$cats[]=$cat;}
   return $cats;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using aggregates such as `count`, you need to supply a `group by` when wanting to return multiple results.

```
SELECT COUNT(tA.id) as classifieds, tC.name as name, tC.id as id
FROM categories as tC LEFT JOIN classifieds as tA ON tA.categories_id=tC.id
GROUP BY tC.name, tC.id
ORDER BY tC.name
```

This will return each category (id/name) with the count of classifieds.

Comment: That's it! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using count in the select, just one row is returned.

You can use `mysql_num_rows` to get the number of rows returned.

```
function list_count()
{
   $q="SELECT tC.name as name, tC.id as id
   FROM categories as tC LEFT JOIN classifieds as tA ON tA.categories_id=tC.id
   ORDER BY tC.name";
   $result=mysql_query($q);
   $cats=array();

   $numberOfRows = mysql_num_rows($result);

   while($cat=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {$cats[]=$cat;}
   return $cats;
}
```

Comment: Looks like I just needed a GROUP BY. see sgeddes answer above, that worked for me. thanks for your help!